# Avg times in mm:ss.0 format

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I have a range of times formatted as mm:ss.0. The problem is trying to average these times.

```
Time    AVG
2:44.35 
2:42.88 
2:47.49 
2:48.86 
2:56.31 00:00.0
```

Comment: Are they stored as text? Or as a number format? (Select one of the cells and look at the formula bar)

Comment: If they were text-formatted then I'd expect #DIV/0! error as a result - are you using a formula to get the average - if so can you supply the formula?

Comment: Thanks Kevin & Barry. The format is as I say in the text "heading", formatted as mm:ss.0. I've tried several approaches in the formula, from "=AVERAGEA(F3,F4,F5,F6,F7)" to sumproduct with a divide by n to many others. The end result is always "00:00.0" as shown above. I'm really at my wits end.

Answer (score 1):

From your last comment I'd say your values are definitely formatted as text, `AVERAGEA` will return 0 instead of #DIV/0! for `AVERAGE`.

It's not always easy to see if values are formatted as text but two options are:

1) Try to change the format to "Number". If you see no difference then you have text values

2) Use a test in another cell, e.g. `=ISNUMBER(F3)` - I suspect that will return FALSE here

To change the format to a numeric one, when you have text values, is not possible with cell formatting. You can try using "Text to columns" functionality to do so, just select the data, F3:F7 and then do this:

`Data > Text to columns > Finish`

...now your original formula should work.....

[If that changes the format of your data you might have to set the format to mm:ss.0]

....or without changing the data you can use a formula to convert to numbers and average all in one hit, e.g. an "array formula" like this

`=AVERAGE(F3:F7+0)`

which needs to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
....or a non-array version

`=SUMPRODUCT(F3:F7+0)/COUNTA(F3:F7)`

In all cases format the result cell with the same format, i.e. `mm:ss.0`